# How can i dynamically add an Input select element on click of a button in ember

Tags: dom, ember.js, handlebars.js

Am creating an ember application where am in need of dynamicaly adding a select element which will have options fetched from a server. so the select elements look like this.[image] And instead of having all dropdown boxes predefined i need to add them dynamicaly like on a click of a button like( + add more). like
[image]

and each of those drop down boxes should contain the datas that is fetched from the server. plus i need a way to get the datas from those dynamically created select fields.

my .hbs for  the current drop down page is..

map.hbs

```
<center><h4>Map</h4></center>
<container class = "cond">
{{#each this.model.sf as |row|}}
    <select class = "sel">
        {{#each this.model.sf as |sf|}}
        <option value = {{sf.attrname}}>{{sf.attrname}}</option>
        {{/each}}
        
    </select><br>
{{/each}}
```

I tried ember-dynamic-fields but its depracted and I couldnt able to use it.. and all other solutions on web or for ember way older versions.. nothing works on ember 4.6 so could anyone helpout?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess Simple js code did the magic of adding and retriving data.. pity of me after finding out.. And for some dynamic ember formdata the previous answer from nullvox helped out.. so  here is the code

.hbs

```
<table class="table">
    <th>
    <td>Sf</td>
    </th>
    <th>
    <td>Db</td>
    </th>

    <tbody id = "map">

   </tbody>


   </table>
   <button class = "btn btn-sm btn-primary" type="button" {{action "submit"}}>Submit</button>
   <button class = "btn btn-success btn-sm" onclick = {{action "get"}} type="button">Add another</button>
```

controller code for creating element

```
 @action
  get() {
    let div = document.getElementById('map');
    let tr = document.createElement('tr');
    let td = document.createElement('td');
    let td2 = document.createElement('td');
    var select = document.createElement('select');
    select.setAttribute('class', 'sfselect');
    div.appendChild(tr);
    tr.appendChild(td);
    td.appendChild(select);

    for (var i = 0; i < sf.length; i++) {
      var option = document.createElement('option');
      option.value = sf[i];
      option.text = sf[i];
      select.appendChild(option);
    }
    var select2 = document.createElement('select');
    select2.setAttribute('class', 'dbselect');
    tr.appendChild(td2);
    td2.appendChild(select2);

    for (var i = 0; i < db.length; i++) {
      var option = document.createElement('option');
      option.value = db[i];
      option.text = db[i];
      select2.appendChild(option);
    }
  }
```

controller code for getting data

```
  @action submit() {
    var sfattr = document.querySelectorAll('.sfselect');
    var dbattr = document.querySelectorAll('.dbselect');
    var sf = [];
    var db = [];
    console.log(sfattr.length);
    let datas;
    for (var i = 0; i < sfattr.length; i++) {
      sf[i] = sfattr[i].value;
      db[i] = dbattr[i].value;
    }
    let m1 = sf.toString();
    let m2 = db.toString();
    $.ajax({
      url: 'http://localhost:8080/lorduoauth/Map',
      method: 'POST',
      contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
      data: {
        m1: m1,
        m2: m2,
      },

      success: function (response) {
        console.log(datas);
        alert(response);
      },
      error: function (xhr, status, error) {
        var errorMessage = xhr.status + ': ' + xhr.statusText;
        alert('error' + errorMessage);
      },
    });
  }
```

thus the output looks like this
[image]

Comment: works in jsp too right??

Comment: Manually manipulating the DOM in any frontend framework could be problematic in the future. Be careful ❤️

Comment: Thank you so much for the insight.. I will try again with the answer you told and modify it according to my data and repost it.

Answer (score 1):

Using *The Platform*'s native FormData functionality, [demo'd here](https://limber.glimdown.com/edit?format=glimdown&t=%23%20Forms%0A%0A%23%23%23%20Using%20_The%20Platform_%0A%0AVanilla%20JavaScript%20has%20everything%20we%20need%20to%20handle%20form%20data%2C%20de-sync%20it%20from%20our%20source%20data%20and%20collect%20all%20user%20input%20upon%20submission.%0A%0AOther%20abstractions%2C%20such%20as%20the%20%22changeset%22%20concept%20contain%20a%20lot%20of%20this%20functionality%20and%20have%20additional%20utilities%20such%20as%20rollback%2C%20snapshots%2C%20forking%2C%20etc%2C%20but%20that%20is%20a%20topic%20for%20another%20demo.%0A%0AIn%20the%20form%20below%2C%20we%20create%20a%20Vanilla%E2%84%A2%20%5BHTML%20form%5D%5B2%5D%2C%20and%20only%20add%20%22Ember%22%20code%20for%20handling%20the%20form%20submission%20and%20field%20inputs.%20By%20default%2C%20form%20submissions%20will%20cause%20a%20page%20reload%2C%20so%20in%20a%20single-page-app%2C%20we%20need%20to%20prevent%20that%20default%20behavior.%0A%0AUsing%20the%20native%20API%2C%20%5BFormData%5D%5B1%5D%2C%20we%20can%20gather%20the%20user%20inputs%20when%20the%20user%20presses%20the%20submit%20button.%0A%0A%60%60%60gjs%20live%0Aimport%20%7B%20on%20%7D%20from%20%27%40ember%2Fmodifier%27%3B%0Aimport%20%7B%20cell%20%7D%20from%20%27ember-resources%27%3B%0A%0Aconst%20state%20%3D%20cell()%3B%0A%0Aconst%20handleInput%20%3D%20(event)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20let%20formData%20%3D%20new%20FormData(event.currentTarget)%3B%0A%20%20let%20data%20%3D%20Object.fromEntries(formData.entries())%3B%0A%0A%20%20state.current%20%3D%20JSON.stringify(data%2C%20null%2C%202)%3B%0A%7D%3B%0A%0Aconst%20handleSubmit%20%3D%20(%20event)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20event.preventDefault()%3B%0A%20%20handleInput(event)%3B%0A%7D%3B%0A%0A%3Ctemplate%3E%0A%20%20%3Cform%0A%20%20%20%20%7B%7Bon%20%27input%27%20handleInput%7D%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%7B%7Bon%20%27submit%27%20handleSubmit%7D%7D%0A%20%20%20%20class%3D%22grid%20gap-2%22%0A%20%20%20%20style%3D%22max-width%3A%20300px%22%0A%20%20%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Clabel%3E%20First%20Name%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cinput%20name%3D%27firstName%27%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3C%2Flabel%3E%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%3Clabel%3E%20Favorite%20Date%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cinput%20type%3D%27date%27%20name%3D%27favoriteDate%27%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3C%2Flabel%3E%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cbutton%20type%3D%27submit%27%3ESubmit%3C%2Fbutton%3E%0A%20%20%3C%2Fform%3E%0A%0A%20%20%3Cbr%3E%3Cbr%3E%0A%0A%20%20FormData%3A%0A%20%20%3Cpre%3E%7B%7Bstate.current%7D%7D%3C%2Fpre%3E%0A%0A%20%20%3Cstyle%3E%0A%20%20%20%20input%20%7B%20border%3A%201px%20solid%3B%20%7D%0A%20%20%3C%2Fstyle%3E%0A%3C%2Ftemplate%3E%0A%60%60%60%0A%0A%3Chr%3E%0A%0A%23%23%23%20%22Platform%22%20References%0A%20-%20%5B%60%3Cform%3E%60%20on%20MDN%5D%5B2%5D%0A%20-%20%5B%60FormData%60%20on%20MDN%5D%5B1%5D%0A%0A%23%23%23%20Ember%20References%0A%20-%20%5Bthe%20%60on%60%20modifier%5D%5B3%5D%0A%0A%0A%5B1%5D%3A%20https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.mozilla.org%2Fen-US%2Fdocs%2FWeb%2FAPI%2FFormData%0A%5B2%5D%3A%20https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.mozilla.org%2Fen-US%2Fdocs%2FWeb%2FHTML%2FElement%2Fform%0A%5B3%5D%3A%20https%3A%2F%2Fguides.emberjs.com%2Frelease%2Fcomponents%2Fcomponent-state-and-actions%2F%23toc_html-modifiers-and-actions%0A).

I think we can generate any number of inputs based on input data in the following way:

- Store the form's state in some variable
- conditionally show further select / inputs based on the properties in that form state.

Code-wise, that'd look like this:

```
{{#if (dataHasValueFor "fieldName")}}
  Show previously hidden field
{{/if}}
```

And of course the devil is in the implementation details, so, a full working example (with sample data I made up -- we can iterate on this if you want for your specific data set, just leave a comment on this post/answer).

```
import Component from '@glimmer/component';
import { tracked } from '@glimmer/tracking';
import { on } from '@ember/modifier';
import { get } from '@ember/helper';

// This could be your model data from your route
const DATA = {
  fruits: [ 
    'apple', 'banana', 'orange', 'mango', 
    'watermellon', 'avacado', 'tomato?'
  ],
  veggies: ['cocumber', 'tomato?', 'green bean', 'kale', 'spinach'], 
  peppers: ['carolina reaper', 'habanero', 'jalapeño']
}

export default class Demo extends Component {
  @tracked formData;

  get categories() {
    return Object.keys(DATA);
  }

  handleInput = (event) => {
    let formData = new FormData(event.currentTarget);
    let data = Object.fromEntries(formData.entries());    

    this.formData = data;
  }

  handleSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    handleInput(event);
  }

  isSelected = (name, value) => this.formData?.[name] === value;
  
  <template>
    <form
      {{on 'input' this.handleInput}}
      {{on 'submit' this.handleSubmit}}
    >
      <label>
        Food Category<br>
        <select name="category" placeholder="Select...">
          <option selected disabled>Select a food group</option>
          {{#each this.categories as |name|}}
            <option 
              value={{name}} 
              selected={{this.isSelected "category" name}}
             >
              {{name}}
            </option>
          {{/each}}
        </select>
      </label>

      <hr>
      {{#let (get this.formData "category") as |selectedCategory|}}
        {{#if selectedCategory}}
          <label>
            {{selectedCategory}}<br>
            <select name={{selectedCategory}}>
              <option selected disabled>
                Select {{selectedCategory}}
              </option>
              {{#each (get DATA selectedCategory) as |food|}}
                <option 
                  value={{food}} 
                  selected={{this.isSelected selectedCategory food}}
                >
                 {{food}}
                </option>
              {{/each}}
            </select>
          </label>
        {{/if}}
      {{/let}}

  
    </form>
    <hr>
    FormData:
    <pre>{{toJson this.formData}}</pre>
  </template>
}


const toJson = (input) => JSON.stringify(input, null, 4);
```

This demo is interactive [here, on limber.glimdown.com](https://limber.glimdown.com/edit?format=gjs&t=import%20Component%20from%20%27%40glimmer%2Fcomponent%27%3B%0Aimport%20%7B%20tracked%20%7D%20from%20%27%40glimmer%2Ftracking%27%3B%0Aimport%20%7B%20on%20%7D%20from%20%27%40ember%2Fmodifier%27%3B%0Aimport%20%7B%20get%20%7D%20from%20%27%40ember%2Fhelper%27%3B%0A%0A%2F%2F%20This%20could%20be%20your%20model%20data%20from%20your%20route%0Aconst%20DATA%20%3D%20%7B%0A%20%20fruits%3A%20%5B%20%0A%20%20%20%20%27apple%27%2C%20%27banana%27%2C%20%27orange%27%2C%20%27mango%27%2C%20%0A%20%20%20%20%27watermellon%27%2C%20%27avacado%27%2C%20%27tomato%3F%27%0A%20%20%5D%2C%0A%20%20veggies%3A%20%5B%27cocumber%27%2C%20%27tomato%3F%27%2C%20%27green%20bean%27%2C%20%27kale%27%2C%20%27spinach%27%5D%2C%20%0A%20%20peppers%3A%20%5B%27carolina%20reaper%27%2C%20%27habanero%27%2C%20%27jalape%C3%B1o%27%5D%0A%7D%0A%0Aexport%20default%20class%20Demo%20extends%20Component%20%7B%0A%20%20%40tracked%20formData%3B%0A%0A%20%20get%20categories()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20return%20Object.keys(DATA)%3B%0A%20%20%7D%0A%0A%20%20handleInput%20%3D%20(event)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20let%20formData%20%3D%20new%20FormData(event.currentTarget)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20let%20data%20%3D%20Object.fromEntries(formData.entries())%3B%20%20%20%20%0A%0A%20%20%20%20this.formData%20%3D%20data%3B%0A%20%20%7D%0A%0A%20%20handleSubmit%20%3D%20(event)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20event.preventDefault()%3B%0A%20%20%20%20handleInput(event)%3B%0A%20%20%7D%0A%0A%20%20isSelected%20%3D%20(name%2C%20value)%20%3D%3E%20this.formData%3F.%5Bname%5D%20%3D%3D%3D%20value%3B%0A%20%20%0A%20%20%3Ctemplate%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cform%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%7Bon%20%27input%27%20this.handleInput%7D%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%7Bon%20%27submit%27%20this.handleSubmit%7D%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Clabel%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Food%20Category%3Cbr%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cselect%20name%3D%22category%22%20placeholder%3D%22Select...%22%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Coption%20selected%20disabled%3ESelect%20a%20food%20group%3C%2Foption%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%7B%23each%20this.categories%20as%20%7Cname%7C%7D%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Coption%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20value%3D%7B%7Bname%7D%7D%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20selected%3D%7B%7Bthis.isSelected%20%22category%22%20name%7D%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%7Bname%7D%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Foption%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%7B%2Feach%7D%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fselect%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Flabel%3E%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Chr%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%7B%23let%20(get%20this.formData%20%22category%22)%20as%20%7CselectedCategory%7C%7D%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%7B%23if%20selectedCategory%7D%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Clabel%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%7BselectedCategory%7D%7D%3Cbr%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cselect%20name%3D%7B%7BselectedCategory%7D%7D%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Coption%20selected%20disabled%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Select%20%7B%7BselectedCategory%7D%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Foption%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%7B%23each%20(get%20DATA%20selectedCategory)%20as%20%7Cfood%7C%7D%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Coption%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20value%3D%7B%7Bfood%7D%7D%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20selected%3D%7B%7Bthis.isSelected%20selectedCategory%20food%7D%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%7Bfood%7D%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Foption%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%7B%2Feach%7D%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fselect%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Flabel%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%7B%2Fif%7D%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%7B%2Flet%7D%7D%0A%0A%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fform%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Chr%3E%0A%20%20%20%20FormData%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cpre%3E%7B%7BtoJson%20this.formData%7D%7D%3C%2Fpre%3E%0A%20%20%3C%2Ftemplate%3E%0A%7D%0A%0A%0Aconst%20toJson%20%3D%20(input)%20%3D%3E%20JSON.stringify(input%2C%20null%2C%204)%3B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%0A)

Note that the syntax used here is what will be default in the upcoming *`Polaris`* Edition of Ember, and is available via [ember-template-imports](https://github.com/ember-template-imports/ember-template-imports)

---

### Update (after comments)

[Demo here](https://limber.glimdown.com/edit?format=gjs&t=import%20Component%20from%20%27%40glimmer%2Fcomponent%27%3B%0Aimport%20%7B%20tracked%20%7D%20from%20%27%40glimmer%2Ftracking%27%3B%0Aimport%20%7B%20on%20%7D%20from%20%27%40ember%2Fmodifier%27%3B%0Aimport%20%7B%20get%20%7D%20from%20%27%40ember%2Fhelper%27%3B%0A%0Aexport%20default%20class%20Demo%20extends%20Component%20%7B%0A%20%20%40tracked%20formData%3B%0A%0A%20%20handleInput%20%3D%20(event)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20let%20formData%20%3D%20new%20FormData(event.currentTarget)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20let%20data%20%3D%20Object.fromEntries(formData.entries())%3B%20%20%20%20%0A%0A%20%20%20%20this.formData%20%3D%20data%3B%0A%20%20%7D%0A%0A%20%20handleSubmit%20%3D%20(event)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20event.preventDefault()%3B%0A%20%20%20%20handleInput(event)%3B%0A%20%20%7D%0A%0A%20%20%3Ctemplate%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cform%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%7Bon%20%27input%27%20this.handleInput%7D%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%7Bon%20%27submit%27%20this.handleSubmit%7D%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%3E%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cdiv%20class%3D%22grid%22%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Clabel%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Name%20%3Cinput%20type%3D%22checkbox%22%20name%3D%27hasName%27%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Flabel%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Clabel%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Email%20%3Cinput%20type%3D%22checkbox%22%20name%3D%27hasEmail%27%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Flabel%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Clabel%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Alias%20%3Cinput%20type%3D%22checkbox%22%20name%3D%27hasAlias%27%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Flabel%3E%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Chr%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%7B%23if%20(get%20this.formData%20%27hasName%27)%7D%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Clabel%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Name%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cinput%20type%3D%22text%22%20name%3D%22name%22%20class%3D%22border%22%20%2F%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Flabel%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%7B%2Fif%7D%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%7B%23if%20(get%20this.formData%20%27hasEmail%27)%7D%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Clabel%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Email%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cinput%20type%3D%22email%22%20name%3D%22email%22%20class%3D%22border%22%20%2F%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Flabel%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%7B%2Fif%7D%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%7B%23if%20(get%20this.formData%20%27hasAlias%27)%7D%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Clabel%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Alias%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cinput%20type%3D%22text%22%20name%3D%22alias%22%20class%3D%22border%22%20%2F%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Flabel%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%7B%2Fif%7D%7D%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fdiv%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fform%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Chr%3E%0A%20%20%20%20FormData%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cpre%3E%7B%7BtoJson%20this.formData%7D%7D%3C%2Fpre%3E%0A%20%20%3C%2Ftemplate%3E%0A%7D%0A%0A%0Aconst%20toJson%20%3D%20(input)%20%3D%3E%20JSON.stringify(input%2C%20null%2C%204)%3B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%0A)

I took some liberties with the *how* the fields are dynamic, because I think this more easily shows the concept asked about in the question: dynamically showing fields in a form.

```js
import Component from '@glimmer/component';
import { tracked } from '@glimmer/tracking';
import { on } from '@ember/modifier';
import { get } from '@ember/helper';

export default class Demo extends Component {
  @tracked formData;

  handleInput = (event) => {
    let formData = new FormData(event.currentTarget);
    let data = Object.fromEntries(formData.entries());    

    this.formData = data;
  }

  handleSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    handleInput(event);
  }

  <template>
    <form
      {{on 'input' this.handleInput}}
      {{on 'submit' this.handleSubmit}}
    > 
      <div class="grid">
        <label>
          Name <input type="checkbox" name='hasName'>
        </label>
        <label>
          Email <input type="checkbox" name='hasEmail'>
        </label>
        <label>
          Alias <input type="checkbox" name='hasAlias'>
        </label>

        <hr>
      
        {{#if (get this.formData 'hasName')}}
           <label>
             Name
             <input type="text" name="name" class="border" />
           </label>
        {{/if}}
        {{#if (get this.formData 'hasEmail')}}
           <label>
             Email
             <input type="email" name="email" class="border" />
           </label>
        {{/if}}
        {{#if (get this.formData 'hasAlias')}}
           <label>
             Alias
             <input type="text" name="alias" class="border" />
           </label>
        {{/if}}

      </div>
    
    </form>
    <hr>
    FormData:
    <pre>{{toJson this.formData}}</pre>
  </template>
}


const toJson = (input) => JSON.stringify(input, null, 4);
```

And... since it seems you have a lot of fields, you may want to go as dynamic as possible:

[demo here](https://limber.glimdown.com/edit?format=gjs&t=import%20Component%20from%20%27%40glimmer%2Fcomponent%27%3B%0Aimport%20%7B%20tracked%20%7D%20from%20%27%40glimmer%2Ftracking%27%3B%0Aimport%20%7B%20on%20%7D%20from%20%27%40ember%2Fmodifier%27%3B%0Aimport%20%7B%20get%2C%20concat%20%7D%20from%20%27%40ember%2Fhelper%27%3B%0A%0Aconst%20FIELDS%20%3D%20%5B%27name%27%2C%20%27email%27%2C%20%27alias%27%5D%3B%0A%0Aexport%20default%20class%20Demo%20extends%20Component%20%7B%0A%20%20%40tracked%20formData%3B%0A%0A%20%20handleInput%20%3D%20(event)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20let%20formData%20%3D%20new%20FormData(event.currentTarget)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20let%20data%20%3D%20Object.fromEntries(formData.entries())%3B%20%20%20%20%0A%0A%20%20%20%20this.formData%20%3D%20data%3B%0A%20%20%7D%0A%0A%20%20handleSubmit%20%3D%20(event)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20event.preventDefault()%3B%0A%20%20%20%20handleInput(event)%3B%0A%20%20%7D%0A%0A%20%20%3Ctemplate%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cform%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%7Bon%20%27input%27%20this.handleInput%7D%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%7Bon%20%27submit%27%20this.handleSubmit%7D%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%3E%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cdiv%20class%3D%22grid%22%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%7B%23each%20FIELDS%20as%20%7Cfield%7C%7D%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Clabel%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%7Bfield%7D%7D%20%3Cinput%20type%3D%22checkbox%22%20name%3D%27has-%7B%7Bfield%7D%7D%27%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Flabel%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%7B%2Feach%7D%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Chr%3E%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%7B%23each%20FIELDS%20as%20%7Cfield%7C%7D%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%7B%23if%20(get%20this.formData%20(concat%20%27has-%27%20field))%7D%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Clabel%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%7Bfield%7D%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cinput%20type%3D%22text%22%20name%3D%7B%7Bfield%7D%7D%20class%3D%22border%22%20%2F%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Flabel%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%7B%2Fif%7D%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%7B%2Feach%7D%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fdiv%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fform%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Chr%3E%0A%20%20%20%20FormData%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cpre%3E%7B%7BtoJson%20this.formData%7D%7D%3C%2Fpre%3E%0A%20%20%3C%2Ftemplate%3E%0A%7D%0A%0A%0Aconst%20toJson%20%3D%20(input)%20%3D%3E%20JSON.stringify(input%2C%20null%2C%204)%3B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%0A)

which is the following code:

```
  <form
      {{on 'input' this.handleInput}}
      {{on 'submit' this.handleSubmit}}
    > 
      <div class="grid">
        {{#each FIELDS as |field|}}
          <label>
            {{field}} <input type="checkbox" name='has-{{field}}'>
          </label>
        {{/each}}
        <hr>

        {{#each FIELDS as |field|}}
          {{#if (get this.formData (concat 'has-' field))}}
             <label>
               {{field}}
               <input type="text" name={{field}} class="border" />
             </label>
          {{/if}}
        {{/each}}
       
      </div>
    </form>
```

Comment: hi.. thank you.. but what i needed was.. instead of those multiple select columns i need one as default and if user wants another there should be a button like add more and when selected a new select field should appear

Comment: sorry if i couldnt convey it correctly.. now i have updated the question

Comment: no worries, so to clarify: you want a select input to show up when a user clicks a button? do you want this to happen infinitely? are all selections to be placed in an array?

Comment: for  all the options that is listed in the option box.. like for example if the select has options like [email,name,alias] the user first selects email then click add more now the option should contain [name,alias] the user can either stop at where he wills or go on until everything in the option is filled out..

Comment: Updated -- the concept is mostly the same -- I used inputs tho, because they're much simpler than selects